# Many to many relations

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I want have 3 models: order, product, attribute. Every order can have many attributes. Every product can have many attributes, and of course order can have many products. Here are my models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer

    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
    has_and_belongs_to_many :attributes
    has_one :invoice_address, class_name: 'OrderAddress'
    has_one :delivery_address, class_name: 'OrderAddress'

    validates :number, presence: true
    validates :total_amount, presence: true
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
    has_and_belongs_to_many :attributes
end
```

and attribute.rb

```
class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

I based my code on this post http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-model-many-many-association The problem is when I want to create new order:

```
dev_customer = Customer.create(:name => 'dev')

dev_user = dev_customer.users.create(:email => 'test@test.pl', :password => 'bk020488', :password_confirmation => 'bk020488')

first_order = dev_customer.orders.create(:number => 1, :total_amount => 555, :paid_amount => 555)

first_order.products.create(:name => 'First product', :price => 111, :qty => 1)
first_order.products.create(:name => 'Second product', :price => 222, :qty => 2)
```

It breaks on line 5 with message

> undefined method `keys' for #

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

dev_customer.users returns an array of users. This is not what you want.

In that case you should enter something like this:

```
first_order = Order.create(:customer_id => dev_customer.id, :number => 1, :total_amount => 555, :paid_amount => 555)
```

This answers your main question.

You might want to look at a couple other elements:

- In most cases, for many to many associations, the has_many :through pattern is preferable
- Your order and its total amount should be calculated directly from the products
- The paid amount could come from records in a 'Payment' model
- To be semantically correct, products should describe the products and what you call products right now should be an shopping card item.

Anyway, have fun.